# What constitutes an "edit" for badges?

Tags: discussion, editing, badges

What counts as editing, specifically for badges such as Strunk & White, Copy Editor, Excavator and Archaeologist?

- Does retagging count?
- Editing my own posts?
- Rollbacks? (I assume so.)
- Flagging?
- Other ways to edit that I'm missing?

Can I see in my profile the total number of edits I've made?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this at meta.stackoverflow:

> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to CW posts do count
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> - Tag wiki edits do count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do    count, 
>     once approved

[Strunk & White badge missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing)

[Does retagging a question count as an edit for Strunk & White?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28454/does-retagging-a-question-count-as-an-edit)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

These are several question. The answer to

> Can I see in my profile the total number of edits I've made?

is that you can't find that info in your profile. But you can find it in another place. Namely by checking out the [Editors tab](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=editors) under Users, looking at [All](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) and searching for your name, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=root45

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to N.N. and Vojtech Trefny's answers, [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445) on meta.stackoverflow answers all my questions with an answer from Jeff Atwood.